# Select n rows of dataframe for each value in column A where n is the value in column C

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the below dataframe

From it, I want to select only n number of rows per salesman where n is the corresponding sales_limit for each salesperson

So, the new dataframe created from the below example, will not have the 3rd row (clint id - ghi) and the sixth rows (client id - pqr) as the corresponding sales limit for both A and B are 2.
For C, all will be selected as the limit (4) is higher than the number of rows assigned.

| salesman | client_id | sales_limit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | abc | 2 |
| A | def | 2 |
| A | ghi | 2 |
| B | jkl | 2 |
| B | mno | 2 |
| B | pqr | 2 |
| C | stu | 4 |
| C | vwx | 4 |
| C | yz | 4 |

Please note: the list of salesman is dynamic, the names and their limits will change every week in the table

I  had an idea of doing a groupby based on the salesman names and then select :n-1 rows per salesman but since the table row numbers might change, I wasnt able to figure a way to account for that.
Can someone please help with the code for above changes in python, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `groupby` then slice each group with `sales_limit`

```py
out = (df.groupby('salesman', as_index=False, group_keys=False)
       .apply(lambda g: g.iloc[:g['sales_limit'].iloc[0]]))
```

```
print(out)

  salesman client_id  sales_limit
0        A       abc            2
1        A       def            2
3        B       jkl            2
4        B       mno            2
6        C       stu            4
7        C       vwx            4
8        C        yz            4
```

Comment: `df.groupby('salesman', as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.head(x['sales_limit'].iloc[0]))`  I used head, slightly more readable.  Maybe. +1

Answer (score 2):

For efficiency, use a comparison with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df.groupby('salesman').cumcount().lt(df['sales_limit'])]
```

Output:

```
  salesman client_id  sales_limit
0        A       abc            2
1        A       def            2
3        B       jkl            2
4        B       mno            2
6        C       stu            4
7        C       vwx            4
8        C        yz            4
```

Intermediates:

```
  salesman client_id  sales_limit  cumcount  cumcount < sales_limit
0        A       abc            2         0                    True
1        A       def            2         1                    True
2        A       ghi            2         2                   False
3        B       jkl            2         0                    True
4        B       mno            2         1                    True
5        B       pqr            2         2                   False
6        C       stu            4         0                    True
7        C       vwx            4         1                    True
8        C        yz            4         2                    True
```

Answer (score 0):

For this I would leverage `pandas groupby`, as well as `apply`.

import `pandas` and generate `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'salesman':['A']*3+['B']*3+['C']*3,'client_id':list('ABCDEFGHI'),'sales_limit':[2]*6+[4]*3})
```

generate a dictionary with the limit per salesperson

```
limits = df.groupby('salesman')['sales_limit'].max().to_dict()
```

use `apply` and `iloc` to print the first x rows

```
df.groupby('salesman').apply(lambda x:x.iloc[:limits[x.name]])
```

Comment: Getting blank dataframe with this